Difficult First Order ODE
The ODE is$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}+\frac{x}{y}=-x^2$$ I tried solving this ODE by creating a homogeneous form, exact differential form, Bernoulli's form(reducible to linear), but it did not work out. So, I tried multiplying $y$ throughout the equation and taking Laplace transform of both sides $($taking $y=f(x)$$)$:
$$\mathcal L(yy')+\frac1{s^2}=-F''(s)$$
To evaluate $\mathcal L(yy')$, I tried integrating by parts. but it turned to be in terms of $\mathcal L(y^2)$ which also I am not able to solve:
$$\mathcal L(yy')=\int_0^{\infty}f(x)f'(x)e^{-sx}\mathrm dx$$
$$=\frac{(f(x))^2}{2}e^{-sx}|_0^{\infty}+s\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(f(x))^2}{2}e^{-sx}\mathrm dx$$
$$=\frac{-(f(0))^2}{2}+\frac{s}{2}\int_0^{\infty}(f(x))^2e^{-sx}\mathrm dx$$
Any help regarding how to approach this would be highly appreciated.

I don't know. I discovered this ODE by slightly modifying one of my homework questions.

See https://mathoverflow.net/a/41181

Are you interesting in this particular method or solving this ODE by any means ?

Any other method is also fine, but I would like to know if it can be reduced to any of the forms mentioned.

@ClaudeLeibovici, could you please elaborate on how the solution of this DE contains a polynomial series?

I assumed it could be possible

A solution for the homogeneous ODE is $y(x)=\pm \sqrt{c_1-x^2}$

@gpmath, what can be done with that? I am not able to make a guess for a non-homogeneous solution to proceed as in second order linear constant coefficient non-homogeneous ODEs.

Find a series solution, here the series solution of 8th order.
$$y! \left(x\right)=y_{0}-\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{y_{0}} x^{2}-\frac{1}{3} x^{3}-\frac{1}{8} \frac{1}{y_{0}^{3}} x^{4}-\frac{1}{15} \frac{1}{y_{0}^{2}} x^{5}-\frac{1}{16} \frac{1}{y_{0}^{5}} x^{6}-\frac{2}{35} \frac{1}{y_{0}^{4}} x^{7}+\mathrm{O}! \left(x^{8}\right)$$

@gpmath how did you find that?

@RakshithPL You may have a look here MSE_Q4970076A

@gpmath does this series represent an elementary or non-elementary function? How do I find that?

@RakshithPL Probably a non-elementary function.

@gpmath ok, thanks for the help!
